# C# OpenXml Get DOCX WordStyle Property Simplified Code

Tags: c#, styles, openxml, docx

Just curious if there is a more simplified version to check if the given body has the word style of "Heading3" applied given this sample C# code I wrote learning the OpenXML library.  To be clear, I am just asking given a body element how can I determine if the given body element has what word style applied.  I eventually have to write a program that process numerous .DOCX files and need to process them from a top to bottom approach.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using System.IO;

namespace docxparsing
{
   class Program
   {
    static void Main()
    {
        string file_to_parse = @"C:\temp\sample.docx";

        WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(file_to_parse,false);

        Body body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

        string fooStr
        foreach( var foo in body )
        {
            fooStr = foo.InnerXml;

            /*
                            these 2 comments represent 2 different xml snippets from 'fooStr'. the only way i figure out how to get the word style is by reading
                                    this xml and doing checks for values. i don't know of any other approach in using the body element to check for the applied word style

                <w:pPr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:pStyle w:val="Heading2" />
                <w:pPr xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:pStyle w:val="Heading3" />
            */

            bool hasHeading3 = fooStr.Contains("pStyle w:val=\"Heading3\"");

            if ( hasHeading3 )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("heading3 found");
            }
        }

        doc.Close();
    }
}
```

}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**EDIT**

Here is updated code of one way to do this.  Still not overall happy with it but it works.  Function to look at is *getWordStyleValue(string x)*

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;


namespace docxparsing
{
    class Program
    {
        // ************************************************
        // grab the word style value
        // ************************************************
        static string getWordStyleValue(string x)
        {
            int p = 0;
            p = x.IndexOf("w:pStyle w:val=");
            if ( p == -1 )
            {
                return "";
            }
            p = p + 15;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (true)
            {
                p++;
                char c = x[p];
                if (c != '"')
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            string s = sb.ToString();
            return s;
        }


        // ************************************************
        // Main
        // ************************************************
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string theFile = @"C:\temp\sample.docx";
            WordprocessingDocument doc =  WordprocessingDocument.Open(theFile,false);

            string body_table     = "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Table";
            string body_paragraph = "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph";

            Body body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
            StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter("paragraphs.log");

            foreach (var b in body)
            {
                string body_type = b.ToString();

                if (body_type == body_paragraph)
                {
                    string str = getWordStyleValue(b.InnerXml);

                    if (str == "" || str == "HeadingNon-TOC" || str == "TOC1" || str == "TOC2" || str == "TableofFigures" || str == "AcronymList" )
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    sw1.WriteLine(str + "," + b.InnerText);
                }

                if ( body_type == body_table )
                {
             //       sw1.WriteLine("Table:\n{0}",b.InnerText);
                }
            }

            doc.Close();
            sw1.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: if your goal is to just determine if "heading3" is used at all in the document, you could `break` after finding the first occurrence.

Comment: Hey @MattBurland , thanks for the comment but that isn't my end goal.  What I eventually have to do is process N .DOCX files, transform the data and import them in a proprietary flat file database. The way parsing will work is I have to do action A based on word style xt, action B based on word style qw, and so on...

Comment: This may eventually be relevant, the `Heading3` is language specific and comes from documents created with English version of a Word. Other Word language versions will have the language specific content here (instead of `Heading3` it can be `berschrift3`). The mapping from `Heading 3` to whatever is the `styleId` can be found in `styles.xml` aka `StyleDefinitionsPart`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You could do something like this:

```
bool ContainsHeading3 = body.Descendants<ParagraphSytleId>().Any(psId => psId.Val == "Heading3");
```

This will look at all the `ParagraphStyleId` elements (`w:pStyle` in the xml) and see if *any* of them have the `Val` of `Heading3`.

Comment: Thanks. I understood the code quite well.  Proficient in C# but just learning this OpenXml SDK.  Going to modify it for my needs though.

Answer (score 1):

Just pasting this **Edit** from original post so he has better visibility.

Here is one solution I came up with.  Yes, it a little cody ( if that is a word ) but working LINQ ( my fav ) to optimize a more elegant solution.

--

Here is updated code of one way to do this. Still not overall happy with it but it works. Function to look at is **getWordStyleValue(string x)**

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;


namespace docxparsing
{
    class Program
    {
        // ************************************************
        // grab the word style value
        // ************************************************
        static string getWordStyleValue(string x)
        {
            int p = 0;
            p = x.IndexOf("w:pStyle w:val=");
            if ( p == -1 )
            {
                return "";
            }
            p = p + 15;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (true)
            {
                p++;
                char c = x[p];
                if (c != '"')
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            string s = sb.ToString();
            return s;
        }


        // ************************************************
        // Main
        // ************************************************
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string theFile = @"C:\temp\sample.docx";
            WordprocessingDocument doc =  WordprocessingDocument.Open(theFile,false);

            string body_table     = "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Table";
            string body_paragraph = "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph";

            Body body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
            StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter("paragraphs.log");

            foreach (var b in body)
            {
                string body_type = b.ToString();

                if (body_type == body_paragraph)
                {
                    string str = getWordStyleValue(b.InnerXml);

                    if (str == "" || str == "HeadingNon-TOC" || str == "TOC1" || str == "TOC2" || str == "TableofFigures" || str == "AcronymList" )
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    sw1.WriteLine(str + "," + b.InnerText);
                }

                if ( body_type == body_table )
                {
             //       sw1.WriteLine("Table:\n{0}",b.InnerText);
                }
            }

            doc.Close();
            sw1.Close();
        }
    }
}
```